# What is "the one" referring to?

Tags: pronouns

I read the news report about the attacks happened in Beirut, Lebanon. Here is the link: [Beirut, Also the Site of Deadly Attacks, Feels Forgotten](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/11/16/world/middleeast/beirut-lebanon-attacks-paris.html?_r=0).

This sentence I don't understand.

"But for some in Beirut, that solidarity was mixed with anguish over the fact that just one of the stricken cities — Paris — received a global outpouring of sympathy akin to **the one** lavished on the United States after the 9/11 attacks."

What is "the one" here referring to? Does it mean Paris who lavished on the US? Or does it mean the solidarity? Though I searched some examples about the usage of "akin to", but still a bit confused about "the one" here. What are the synonymous words of "akin to"?

Thanks for helping me!

Comment: "The one" is referring to "an outpouring of sympathy".

Comment: Oh thanks! I should find the subject closest to "the one" . : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... received **a global outpouring of sympathy** akin to **the one** lavished on the United States ...

The one in this context refers to a global outpouring of sympathy, meaning that there are similarities between 9/11 and the recent Paris attacks.

As an aside, I find it amusing (in a dark sort of way) that Anonymous have vowed revenge for Paris but don't appear to give a damn about Lebanon or the Russian airline disaster, the latter of which had *more* casualties than Paris.